# Почему функция arr.filter не работает?

Tags: javascript

Нативный начал только учить - примеры брал с MDN

Вот пример который не работает

```js
var el1 = document.getElementsByClassName('red');
var el2 = document.getElementsByClassName('green');
var el3 = document.getElementsByClassName('blue');
var el4 = document.getElementsByClassName('grey');
var el5 = document.getElementsByClassName('pink');

var arr = [el1,el2,el3,el4,el5];


var rs = arr.filter(function(e) {
 return e.indexOf(el2);
});


console.log(rs);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем filter() почему то не работает ... 
объясните плиз почему так ?

Comment: объясните, что Вы хотите проверить в этой строчке `return e.indexOf(el2);`?

Comment: @Igor  давай  в чат ?

Comment: если бы я еще знал, как его начать (

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77997/discussion-between-fjsevilla-and-ivan-rodriguez

Comment: @Igor  ссылка вверху

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var all = document.querySelectorAll(
  '.red, .green, .blue, .grey, .pink');
var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < all.length; i++)
  arr.push(all[i]);

var reds = arr.filter(function(e) {
  return e.classList.contains("red");
});

arr.forEach(item => item.style.display = 'none');
reds.forEach(item => item.style.display = 'block');

console.log(reds);
```

или сразу

```
arr.forEach(item => 
  item.style.display = item.classList.contains("red")? 'block' : 'none');
```

Если `red` передано как `page.html#red`:

```
var all = document.querySelectorAll('.red, .green, .blue, .grey, .pink');
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);

console.log(hash, all.length);

for(var i = 0; i < all.length; i++)
  all[i].style.display = all[i].classList.contains(hash)? 'block' : 'none';
```